# How to use presenter view to record on one screen?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, recording

I am new to creating powerpoint presentations, using office 360 version, which has been a breeze to create the presentation. Before I created the whole thing, I tested out whether I could record on my laptop using presenter view and as soon as I clicked on Record Slide Show, it came up in presenter view automatically with the notes to the right as expected. The recording showed a perfect full screen version with the audio playing over the top, just like I wanted. I practised a few times and it did this automatically each time.

Now I've finished my presentation and want to record it, using the presenter view on my laptop as I practised, and I can't get it to show the presenter view. What I get now is the current slide centred on the screen, with a notes tab at the top to show or hide notes. Nothing I can do is giving me the presenter view like it did before. I haven't changed any settings or even any content (it's my practice slide - I was checking the audio of a different microphone). I don't seem to be able to find any info online either.

I have tried using the rehearse function, but I don't get any notes at all on there (which is seriously daft! Don't people have notes to help them, which would be needed when practising?? You'd think microsoft would have at least worked that one out by now!) I also tried just starting a slide show, so I could select presenter view from the options at the bottom left, but then I don't get the option to record.

I just don't understand why it's suddenly different. It was much easier to read the notes when they were on the right, rather than floating over the top of the slide when I need to see the slide while I'm recording. Do I really have to connect to a second screen to make it work? I just want to do a practice recording to see how long the presentation will be, so frustrating that I can't get it to do what it did automatically a week ago!

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. And please be very specific! Serious non-techy female here :) Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you have a second screen attached in your first run? In that case, yes you need to attach it again. Presenter view is, from my understanding, meant to give you an alternative view on the screen that is only visible to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seth's comment is correct.  PPT will give you Presenter view by default if you have a second monitor/projector plugged in. Otherwise you get the slideshow on your laptop's screen.

However, start the show, right click and choose "Show presenter view".

Do your happy dance.

Comment: Thank you Seth and Steve. 

I got all that when first getting started with it. I didn't have a second screen attached the first time, I literally changed NOTHING! It's so weird. Can't figure it out. I did use the record function to time it, but it was nowhere near as user-friendly as presenter view, so I'm going to have to just add a second screen and be done with it I think. 

Thanks for your input anyway! Much obliged :)